# How to download all the dependencies of fabric-sdk-go?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I used command "**go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go**" to download fabric-sdk-go and its dependencies. No error happened.

In the golang documentation( https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies ), it said that "Get downloads the packages named by the import paths, along with their dependencies. It then installs the named packages, like 'go install'."

So I originally thought that all the dependencies of fabric-sdk-go would be downloaded **recursively**. But the fact proved that I was wrong.

When I ran command "go install ./..." under fabric-sdk-go directory, many errors "cannot find package" were displayed:
[image]
So my questions are:

1. Does "go get" download dependencies **recursively** or not?
2. How to download **all** the dependencies of fabric-sdk-go, instead of using "go get [a_dependency_package]" to download every single dependency one by one?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no entry point in the root of the project (i.e. no main method) so there is nowhere for the tool to start looking as it doesn't actually do recursive downloads. Instead it looks at the files in the directory you named in the URL and fetches import paths named in those files. For future reference this command will do what you want it to, `go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/...` you can append the triple dot right to your `go get` command

Answer (score -1):

> 1. Does "go get" download dependencies recursively or not?

Yes it does. No need to worry or doubt the documentation

> 2. How to download all the dependencies of fabric-sdk-go, instead of using "go get [a_dependency_package]" to download every single dependency one by one?

Just use go modules: `export GO111MODULE=on` and build your code.

Comment: But why after executing "go get github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go" successfully, the dependencies were still missing? I can't understand. Until later I executed "go get ./...", all dependencies exist under $GOPATH/src